# how to initialize a new array with objects from another array( i get the address, not the value)

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a problem with initializing an array. It shows a new array of memory addresses, not values. I'm wrong, but I can not find the error. It may be very easy, but I hope you will help me.

```
public static void searchCarByBrand(Car[] cars, char ch) {

    System.out.println("the method searchCarByBrand was called with ch = " + ch);
    int carsLenght = cars.length;
    Car[] carsArray = new Car[carsLenght];

    for(Car aCars : cars) {
        System.out.println("this is for each");

        if(getBrand().charAt(0) == ch) {
            System.out.println("this is if");

            for(int i = 0; i< carsArray.length; i++) {
                carsArray[i] = new Car();
                System.out.println("carsArray[" + i + "]: " + carsArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Car {
private static String brand;
private String model;
// private String model;
private String color;
private int horsePower;
private String engineType;
private String gearBoxType;
private String dateOfManufacture;
```

}

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Car car1 = new Car("Mercedes", "slk", "blue", 199, "bnz", "r",
            "18 August 2005");
    Car car2 = new Car("peugeot", "206 cc", "blue", 165,"bnz", "r", "200");
    Car car3 = new Car("peugeot", "206" , "red", 155, "bnz", "r", "2005");

    Car[] carArray = new Car[3];
    carArray[0] = car1;
    carArray[1] = car2;
    carArray[2] = car3;

    System.out.println("this is the result from the 1st method:");
    System.out.println("enter brand:");
    char ch =  scan.next().charAt(0);
    searchCarByBrand(carArray,ch);

}
```

Comment: For completeness, could you add your `Car` class? That would make it easier to give a working example.

Comment: do you have a toString method in your Car class?

Comment: no, I don't have, I will try to add it

Comment: Often the IDE can generate a toString for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print on console try adding **public String toString()** method in car class.
Also in your array you have added an empty car object so it will not print any values

> carsArray[i] = new Car();
>               System.out.println("carsArray[" + i + "]: " + carsArray[i]);

Add toString method in car class

```
    @Override
public String toString() {
    return "Car{" +
            "model='" + model + '\'' +
            ", color='" + color + '\'' +
            ", horsePower=" + horsePower +
            ", engineType='" + engineType + '\'' +
            ", gearBoxType='" + gearBoxType + '\'' +
            ", dateOfManufacture='" + dateOfManufacture + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

Seems like some logical mistake in code 
 if(**aCars**.getBrand().charAt(0) == ch)
 and
 
            carsArray[i] =   <strike>new Car()</strike> **aCars**;

for(Car aCars : cars) {
        System.out.println("this is for each");

```
    if(aCars.getBrand().charAt(0) == ch) {
        System.out.println("this is if");

        for(int i = 0; i< carsArray.length; i++) {
            carsArray[i] = aCars;
            System.out.println("carsArray[" + i + "]: " + carsArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Oh,sorry I forgot this: (this is test in my main method)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now works, but with null.Why ? There are initialized objects in the array.

Comment: @elfcheM : what do you mean by null, null for values? if yes as i said you have not set values for fields in car object. you can try  carsArray[i] = aCars ;

Comment: @elfcheM : updated the answer to solve null, please check and accept the answer if it solve the problem so that other users can find it useful